# Yammer Open Graph Post - How do i do it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook-opengraph, yammer

I am trying to figure out how the payload should be constructed for a Open Graph object to submit to yammer.  I can post a standard message, but i would like to post an opengraph message instead.

```
{
"activity":{
    "actor":{"name":"Sidd Singh",
    "email":"sidd@xyz.com"},
    "action":"create",
    "object": {
        "url":"https://www.sched.do",
        "title":"Lunch Meeting"
    },
    "message":"Hey, let’s get sushi!",
    "users":[
        {"name":"Adarsh Pandit",
        "email":"adarsh@xyz.com"}
    ]
  }
}
```

This is some code nicked from their API documentation but doesn't show me how i should use this in javascript.  Can someone assist me?  Below is my existing code that posts a standard message...

```
yam.request({
        url: "https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/messages.json?network_id=networkname",     //this is one of many REST endpoints that are available
        method: "POST",
        beforeSend: function (req) { //send the access_token in the HTTP header
            req.headers.Authorization = "Bearer " + access_token;
        },
        data: {         
          "network": "networkname",
          "body": "Test Post",
          "group_id": "3719771"
        },
        success: function (data) { //print message response information to the console
            toastr.success('An Item was successfully posted to Yammer', "Yammer Network");  
        },
        error: function (user) {
            toastr.error('There was an error eith the request', "Yammer Network");  
        }
      });
```

Comment: Do you really need to do this client side with JavaScript, or can you you do it server-side? You should never be exposing an OAuth access token like this in client-side code.

Answer (score 0):

This post answered your question: [Yammer Open Graph API Error 400](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24657648/yammer-open-graph-api-error-400/24700842#24700842)

Simply replace the key value pairs in the `data{}` with the activity json strings. Also remember to change the RESTful api endpoint to `https://api.yammer.com/api/v1/activity.json`